Transform scale in cube material cannot accept decimal value
I have set size of cube to be 20 cm. Then i want to transform scale with values x: 0.048 , y: 1, z: 0.048. But strangely it reset all value to x: 1, y: 1, and z:1. Then i want to try with another decimal such as x: 1.2, y: 2, z: 1.2 the panel will automatically reset it into x: 1, y: 1, z: 1. My question is how to set transform scale that can accept decimal number ?


Decimal separator in RCP
Users from different countries use two different decimal separators to work with macOS apps. You can select a decimal separator that you're accustomed to (whether it's a comma , or a period .) through the macOS 15.2 menu:  – System Settings... – General – Language & Region – Number Format. As you can see below, you're able to use comma or period as a decimal separator in Reality Composer Pro.


If the system setting is not applied, restart RCP.

Found the answer, if you want to set decimal number in reality composer pro use comma separator (,)
